# Mono.Webkit (webkit-sharp), access c# objects, functions from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, mono, webkit, gtk

I wrote a simple Gtk Application with a Webkit Browser Widget (WebView) included. I want to access C# Objects (or C# functions) with Javascript in this Application.

Comment: From the Javascript executed inside the WebkitView ?. That's should not be allowed, for security reason. Although I'm not sure, and I can't find the docs right now. It is known that JavaScript inside webpage shouldn't manipulate un-sanboxed objects for security issues.

Comment: But it seems possible with C Code, so I just didn't find a way in the managed c# bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is satisfiable as it's not the direct access, but you can 'access' C# objects and methods this way:
Create class that extends `WebView`, and overwrite `OnResourceRequestStarting()` method to catch javascript ajax requests. You can use them as a method calls from js. As an answer to those requests, you can call `WebView.ExecuteScript()` and pass some parameters.